# Using PHPUnit in PhpStorm using Docker

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, phpstorm

I have a very specific configuration that I have to hold until I can start moving feature from my old PHP 5 application to somewhere else.

I'm trying to tie my testing environment with PhpStorm but I cant figure it out. Since I'm not using Composer, I have to specify phpunit.phar path (which is `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` - a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/phpunit.phar`).  I keep having this error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'Cannot create phar '/usr/local/bin/phpunit', file extension (or combination) not recognised or the directory does not exist' in /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php:181
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php(181): Phar->__construct('/usr/local/bin/...')
>
> #1 /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php(250): IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init()
>
> #2 {main}
>     thrown in /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php on line 181

The setup on my Docker is 
PHP 5.5.9 with PHPUnit 4.8.9

My remote Docker PHP interpreter works in PhpStorm, and my PHPUnit works when I run test in bash (using `docker exec phpunit`) - so it seems that the pieces are working, mostly the glue doesn't work.

Here are my settings
[image: phpunit_framework_settings]

Comment: What it has to do with WebStorm? WebStorm does not support PHP.

Comment: totally right, just corrected my typo

Comment: Please double check that `/usr/local/bin/phpunit.phar` is actually there in the container.

Comment: `root@6649373c4111:/usr/local/bin# ls`
here is my ls output
`composer  phpunit  phpunit.phar  set_tz`

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem with `composer` and the issue is you need to set up a PHPUnit interpreter in PHPStorm with the `autoload.php` file.

- Open Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Test Frameworks
- Click the Plus `+` icon to add a Remote Interpreter
- Select the CLI interpreter previously defined and use existing path mappings
- Select `Use Composer Autoloader`
- Path to script should be `/path/to/vendor/autoload.php`
- Check off `Default configuration file` and set it to `/path/to/phpunit.xml`

I also needed to have the following section in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  my-api:
    # Other contents omitted
    environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=my-api.company.com
```

Where `my-api.company.com` is the server definition name from Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Servers